# Extrude a point layer based on sales figures from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, arcmap

I'm trying to get a SQL query working that takes the total sales figures for a salesperson and uses that to extrude the address of the sales person to give me a 3D view of who is selling most.
I have three tables; salepeople that has spid, an address table that has spaddressid and spgeom. And salestally that has the sales totals. Here is what I have so far;

```
CREATE TABLE sales_extruded AS SELECT sp.spid, ad.spaddressid, ST_Extrude(ad.spgeom, 0,0, st.saletallytotal) as the_geom, st.saletallytotal FROM public."address" ad, public."salestally" st, public."salespeople" sp WHERE st.spid = sp.spid ;
```

I would like to ask for help with two things; how to group all the sales figures for individual salespeople and how to test the geometry that is being created. I've brought the table into ArcMap but nothing is showing up. Ideally I'd like to bring it into ArcScene. Thanks to anyone who can help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a schema, it's difficult to provide accurate and specific help, but here's an attempt. The first query would work if the salestally tables has one row for each salesperson. If you need to sum up values by sales person, you may need something like the second query, which sums the sales for a particular salesperson in the query at each address.

```
CREATE TABLE sales_extruded AS 
 SELECT sp.spid
  , ad.spaddressid
  , ST_Extrude(ad.spgeom, 0,0, st.saletallytotal) as the_geom
  , st.saletallytotal 
 FROM public."address" ad 
 join public."salespeople" sp on sp.spaddressid = ad.spaddressid
 join public."salestally" st on st.spid = sp.spid;



CREATE TABLE sales_extruded AS 
 SELECT sp.spid
  , ad.spaddressid
  , ST_Extrude(ad.spgeom, 0,0, sum(st.saletallytotal)) as the_geom
  , sum(st.saletallytotal) as saletallytotal
 FROM public."address" ad 
 join public."salespeople" sp on sp.spaddressid = ad.spaddressid
 join public."salestally" st on st.spid = sp.spid
 group by sp.spid, ad.spaddressid, ad.spgeom;
```

Comment: Hi George S, sorry for delay in getting back to you. Thanks, that worked. Is there a way to visualize the extruded points? I was thinking ArcScene by have never used it.

Comment: Nevermind George S, I found a tutorial. Thanks again for your help.